# how to correctly include "PureCloudPlatformClientV2" dependencies in lambda function without layers

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Im unable to use aPureCloudPlatformClientV2 library in my aws lambda function. I have tried researching about this but could not succeed.

I first create a new directory and have one .py file for my lambda function. Next, I install through command: "pip install PureCloudPlatformClientV2". After this i test my function locally and it works fine if i call the function right after defining it like this:
def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': "success"
}
```

lambda_handler(None, None)

After testing, i create a zip file and upload it to lambda function with runtime 3.11. It gives me task timed out error no matter how much i increase timeout configuration.